# SerialPort method Read() fail (C#.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm trying to connect, by specific API in C#.NET, to serial port (COM20) on a tablet with OS Windows 7. The process complete the process with this code:

```
public override int ReceiveBytes(int length, byte[] messageSpace, int offset)
{
    return this.serialPort.Read(messageSpace, offset, length);
}
```

The parameters are:

> messageSpace = byte[256] (with all elements = 0), offset = 0 and length = 7

Here I've an error because the call to method returns "error of Timeout". I don't know where the code is wrong ... Although with the opened port mustn't return error...

Also, I thought how develop the app, maybe I need run the app as administrator but I did and had the same trouble.

Does anyone how to help me with the serial port?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Don't set the SerialPort.ReadTimeout property until your code is rock-solid.  Only then can you be sure that a timeout exception is a real timeout and not just tripped by a bug in your code or a basic failure to receive anything from the device.

Comment: Try to confirm communication is there, com-port is working, cable is ok and connected, device is able to send/receive something. Then check how to open com-port properly (perhaps a mistake in configuraton). Then check data packed is correctly send/received (maybe you don't respect read timeouts, etc.). And only then blame `SerialPort.Read`.

Comment: How can I know if the port is truly connected? Because the only way is with the method serialport.IsOpen()... In addition I don't know the behaovoir of my divice, because it's a reader RFID and the first step is connect and them I'll able to be check the port.